# Construct new keras model with logits as output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have `Sequential` model defined. Here are the `input=model.input` and `output=model.output` of the model:

```
(Pdb) input
<tf.Tensor 'input_img_1:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 1) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) output
<tf.Tensor 'model_1/activation_7/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
```

After that I extract the logits as follows: `logits, = output.op.inputs`, then here is the `logits`:

```
(Pdb) logits
<tf.Tensor 'model_1/dense_3/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
```

Why does this work?

```
(Pdb) Model(input, output)
<keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f6917272198>
```

But this does not?

```
(Pdb) Model(input, logits)
*** TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("model_1/dense_3/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Given that both `logits` and `output` are a `tf.Tensor`. I also tried to wrap `logits` around a `Lambda` layer, like so `logits = Lambda((lambda x: x))(logits)`.

Now the error of `Model(input, logits)` is `*** AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'`

Comment: Try: `logits = Lambda((lambda x: x.op.inputs))(output)`

Comment: @MarcinMożejko: I got a new error AttributeError: '_InputList' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Comment: How about `logits = Lambda((lambda x: x.op.inputs[0]))(output)`.

Comment: List index out of range

Comment: Do you have your model compiled?

Comment: Btw. which `keras` version do you use?

Comment: No didn't compile the model. keras is 2.0.8